# Instance Variable loop inside the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have some repeated code inside one of my controllers that I would like to consolidate into a loop, but I can't find any clear instruction on how to do so since this seems to be a unique use case for gmaps4rails.  I tried creating an array of instance variables but it didn't seem to work!  The code I'd like to consolidate:

stores_controller.rb -->

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController

    def map
      @rep1 = Store.where(:user_id => "1")
      @rep2 = Store.where(:user_id => "10")
      @rep3 = Store.where(:user_id => "11")
      @rep4 = Store.where(:user_id => "12")
      @rep5 = Store.where(:user_id => "13")
      @rep6 = Store.where(:user_id => "14")
      @rep7 = Store.where(:user_id => "15")
      @rep8 = Store.where(:user_id => "16")
      @rep9 = Store.where(:user_id => "17")
      @repA = Store.where(:user_id => "18")

      @hash1 = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@rep1) do |store, marker|
        marker.lat store.lat
        marker.lng store.long
        marker.title store.name
        marker.infowindow "#{store.store_infowindow}"
        marker.picture({
           :url => "//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=TP|81DF08|000000",
           :width   => 52,
           :height  => 32
        })

      end
      @hash2 = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@rep2) do |store, marker|
        marker.lat store.lat
        marker.lng store.long
        marker.title store.name
        marker.infowindow "#{store.store_infowindow}"
        marker.picture({
           :url => "//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=BS|267AD2|D9E1FF",
           :width   => 52,
           :height  => 32
        })
      end
      @hash3 = etc, etc, etc...
```

I'll also include the marker loader from my map JS in the view file for good measure,

map.html.erb -->

```
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash1.to_json %>), handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash2.to_json %>),
          handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash3.to_json %>), handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash3.to_json %>),
          handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash4.to_json %>), handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash5.to_json %>),
          handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash6.to_json %>), handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash7.to_json %>),
          handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash8.to_json %>), handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash9.to_json %>),
          handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hashA.to_json %>);
```

The gmaps4rails marker building @hash variables continue their individual loops through all 10 reps beyond these first two indicated here.  The only two variables within these hashes are the 'build_markers(@rep#)' call and the 'chld=TP|81DF08|000000' call which indicates the initials and color of the marker for each user.  I'm a beginner, so for all I know I could be doing this completely wrong from the start!  Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT -->**

My consolidated code, which ended up being as simple as adding a "Marker" column to my user table since that was the only hard-coded variable that needed changing, in the form of '#{store.user.marker}' within the map marker URL:

stores_controller.rb -->

```
def map
  @stores = Store.all
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@stores) do |store, marker|
    marker.lat store.lat
    marker.lng store.long
    marker.title store.name
    marker.infowindow "#{store.store_infowindow}"
    marker.picture({
       :url => "//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=#{store.user.marker}",
       :width   => 52, :height  => 32
    })
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @hash }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this is to simply fetch the records from the db and store the whole collection in one instance variable.

```
@stores = Store.where(user_id: [1, 2, 3])

@markers = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@stores) do |store, marker|
  marker.lat store.lat
  marker.lng store.long
  marker.title store.name
  marker.infowindow "#{store.store_infowindow}"
  # if they need different pictures handle it in the model
  marker.picture({
           :url => "//chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=TP|81DF08|000000",
           :width   => 52,
           :height  => 32
  })
end
```

Doing this:

```
  @rep1 = Store.where(:user_id => "1")
  @rep2 = Store.where(:user_id => "10")
  @rep3 = Store.where(:user_id => "11")
  @rep4 = Store.where(:user_id => "12")
  @rep5 = Store.where(:user_id => "13")
  @rep6 = Store.where(:user_id => "14")
  @rep7 = Store.where(:user_id => "15")
```

Is horrible for performance since each line will create a separate database query. If you are new at ruby I would suggest doing something like http://tryruby.org and learning how to manipulate arrays and hashes and the basics before trying to solve more complex problems.

Comment: Hardcoding IDs into your code is a really bad code smell. It means that you won't be able to test the code since the IDs are created sequentially by the database. Instead you should think about what resources should be available and a sensible way of filtering them.

Comment: This method will limit the colors of the marker though unfortunately, since i need to have dynamic marker colors on the map for each user.

Comment: You should be able to get the user by `store.user` - you can store the colors on the users table. What you are doing is not really a feasible way to build apps...

Comment: Appreciate the guidance, @max.  It gets me off to a great start!